# In Skyrim, how do I move the console command list?

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim

I've bee trying to get more options to show up for orcish armor. I just get orcish invaders. How do I move the list?

Comment: Use page up or down

Comment: you are saying that you`re getting multiple results on console, and you want to scroll them? (probably because they dont fit on your screen)

Comment: The title makes it sound like you want the console window to be in a different position on your screen, but the body makes it sound like it should be scrolled.

Answer (score 1):

if you are wanting to scroll through the list of options displayed after using the help "SOMETHING" command. simply use the page up or down buttons to scroll through it. alternatively, all the id's are shown [here](http://elderscrolls.wikia.com/wiki/Orcish_Armor_(Skyrim)) and if you are wanting to get them through the console, you can use the player.additem ID AMOUNT or player.placeatme ID commands.

Note: for those unfamiliar with console commands, when using the help command you can use multiple words if you surround them in quotes. Ex. help "orcish shield"